# Cannot update large amount of records in orientdb

Tags: orientdb

while update 20000 record by the orientdb java api.got following warning message and start new another procces and update records from beginning .even though previous updating process is run, after updated 12000 record.

warning: connection re-acquired transparently after xxx ms and y retries : no errors will be thrown at application level

I tried to insert 20000 record by increasing time out period. but it doesn't work.
would please help me to stop, start new process.

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: to point you in the right direction we need more info, like if is running in tx or noTx, if you do the update using sql or ODocument api, if you can share your code will help even more/